# wordpressstop  com spam

Tags: support, spam

Several days ago, I flagged as spam an answer (can't remember what Question) that read as follows:

> Nice article.
>
> Just visit
>   `http://www.wordpressstop.com` for lot
>   of articles related to Wordpress.

I just flagged another identical answer left to a new question (and discovered that [the user has left this same comment to 3 total Questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/5773/prasad)).

I assume that, given the rep of the user, that this is a new account - so I assume that the previous account was banned/removed/whatever. But now it's back again.

What do we do about this type of situation? We only get a limited number of "flags", and I don't want to waste rep downvoting spam. Clearly this person intends to keep coming back, even if this new account is banned/removed/whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah, same account. I deleted that previous answer.

Given that this is now a clear spam pattern rather than single occurrence I had sent user a warning and suspended his account for a week.

Please do not hesitate to use flags! It is easiest way for moderators to deal with things and the more you flag appropriately the more weight your opinion on such matters mean to site mechanics (flag weight).

Comment: I should probably research this, as I'm sure the answer must be available already, but: what happens when I exhaust my quota of 10 flags? (I've used 4, I think.) If previous flags are acted on accordingly, are more flags alloted?

Comment: @Chip: Yes, every time two of your flags are accepted, you get one more flag. So you start with 10 flags, use two to mark spam and have 8, the spam flags get accepted and you end up with... 11 flags! It is calculated as [flag weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight), and has some (high) limits and badges when you reach those limits. Summary: the more you flag correctly, the more flags you get.

Comment: Oh, good to know! (Now, I wish I'd flagged all 3 of those spam comments!)